# Different urls for development and production

Tags: linux, codeigniter, nginx

I am trying to set up an CodeIgniter project with NGINX. However, it is an already website which is online, say for example [test.com](http://test.com). This means that the project also has `$config['base_url'] = 'test.com'`. But when I want to setup an NGINX server block I have to define the server name that is the same as the domain in `base_url`, according to [this post](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/). However, I want to have url [test.dev](http://test.dev) for the development and [test.com](http://test.com) should just link to the online website. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Set your ENVIRONMENT variable. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html
For your production

```
 define('ENVIRONMENT','production');
```

and for development

```
 define('ENVIRONMENT','production');
```

and in your config file you can check like this or any variables

```
if(ENVIRONMENT == 'development'){
    $config['base_url'] = 'test.dev';
}else{
    $config['base_url'] = 'test.com';
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but currently my test.dev gives "Problem loading page". Also `access.log` and `error.log` show no requests. My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.dev` file is like the one shown in the link in the original post. I've also created the symbolic link to `sites-enabled`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Adding `127.0.0.1 test.com` to my `/etc/hosts` file results in de "Welcome to nginx!" website when I try to access test.com. In other words, it now redirects to the default page.

Comment: I think this could be your vhost setting issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489919/nginx-static-index-redirect

Answer (score 1):

Create Environments. [Handling Multiple Environments](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html)

In your index.php Find a line which says

```
//define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

Under that line place a check on dirname and paste this code

```
switch(dirname(__FILE__))
{
case 'Path\of\your\live\server\folder':
    define('ENVIRONMENT','production');
break;

case 'path\of\your\local\folder':
    define('ENVIRONMENT','development');
break;
}
```

Now you have a global variable ENVIRONMENT which has values production or development. You can place a switch on this variable and give values to base_url in config.php or choose active group in database.php for DB credentials .

Comment: Apparently I'm having a different issue with nginx before this. See @shafiq his answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In CI, you can define a `config.php` file for each environment you are using.
In your `config` folder, create a `development` folder in which you place a `config.php` file with the `base_url` you need. Then, in that environment, CI will use that new file instead of the main `config.php` file.

Comment: Apparently I'm having a different issue with nginx before this. See @shafiq's answer for more details.